# Nautilus won't open (ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 558...)

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus icon wont open. If I run from terminal, I get:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 558: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) == R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!
```

What should I do to fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

ubuntu settings wont open also

I'm using 18.04

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea on trying to open settings to see, I noticed setting wont open also. But it's 18.04

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/bin/nautilus | egrep "local|not"` and `ldd /usr/bin/gnome-control-center | egrep "local|not"` to the question.